# Pandas - Creating a new column based on conditional math done on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with the following

```
Col A|Col B|Col C
A     1     20
A     2     30
A     3     40
B     1     10
B     2     30
```

I want to add a col D that sums all values in Col C that have the same Col A value but whose Col B val is low than itself. So the result would be

```
    Col A|Col B|Col C|Col D
     A     1     20   20
     A     2     30   50
     A     3     40   90
     B     1     10   10
     B     2     30   40
```

Thank You!

Comment: `df.groupy('col A').cumsum()`?

Comment: Since the data are already ordered this may be `df.groupby('Col A')['Col C'].cumsum()`. But perhaps it's more complicated? Can there be ties in 'Col B' and if so how do they get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,20],
["A",4,30],
["A",3,40],
["B",1,10],
["B",2,30]], columns =  ["Col A","Col B","Col C"])

df = df.sort_values(['Col A','Col B']).groupby('Col A')['Col C'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Another question if you don't mind - lets say there are two rows that are the same, example B, 1, 10, and we want column D to have the same value for both of those and not cumsum it for the next value, how would we do that? I modified the df.sort_values to first do a drop_duplicates with the columns that are not identical removed, but than it ends up with NaNs on the extra rows.